# Not sure whether Deezer Framework is supporting arm64 or not?

Tags: deezer

Apple will required application to support both 32 and 64 bits architecture from February 2015. Deezer SDK for iOS doesn't include arm64 architecture.

So when will the Deezer Team update the SDK  to compatible 64bit architecture?

Comment: This question would be better asked direct to the Deezer Team developers. I'd recommend asking them via their website (I believe http://developers.deezer.com/).

Comment: Iain, there is no platform on the deezer developer site for questions/answers; not even a mail address. They clearly specified that if a developer needs support, they should use stackoverflow with the deezer tag.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see Deezer iOS SDK version 0.9.0 (just passed from beta to official) is 64 bit.

```
Source: executed lipo -info libDeezer.a
```

and obtained

```
Architectures in the fat file: libDeezer.a are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64
```